# Android webview audio not working on Sony Xperia

Tags: android, html, webview, sony, sony-xperia

I am having a very weird problem: a very simple HTML5 file, with a single  tag, that works just fine on every other browser and webview of all handsets, except for the Sony Xperia cellphone and tablets.

There is no error messages (apparently), it just shows the play button but then nothing happens. If I get the same html file and run on other device, it works.

The webview is configured with the usual suspects: plugins enabled, javascript enabled etc..

Comment: I just downloaded the app "Android HTML5 Supported" on my Sony Xperia Z Ultra (Android 4.2.2). The WebView in that app seems to work fine on my device. Since you didn't provide the specific tag/code you used on yours, I can't do much more than that.

Comment: Also, you need to tell us about the audio file you're using, its format, its encoding, and where it's being loaded from.